# Creating a new Normal template in ArcCatalog?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, arccatalog, windows-10

I need to restore my ArcCatalog template to its original default. I am missing the main tab above the toolbar i.e. edit/file/customize etc...I am running ArcCatalog 10.3 on a Windows 10 operating system.

I understand that I need to delete or rename the existing Normal.gxt file in order to generate a new one.  For the life of me I cannot find the template anywhere.

Where is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On my machine which is a Windows 10 computer the normal template that I would delete to restore ArcCatalog to its default settings is here:

C:\Users\Hornbydd\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.2\ArcCatalog

Comment: The only change I had to make to the string was to add my user name (of course) and change the version to 10.3.  Seems to me there should be an easier way to get back to default, but I'm a newbie so what do I know. Thank you again....

Comment: @JPSzaboJr Please remember to click the green accept tick next to the answer that helped you the most. That is the simplest and most rewarding way to thank people here.

Comment: you can replace the `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\` with the `%appdata%` shortcut e.g. `%appdata%\Esri\Desktop10.4\ArcCatalog` gets me to the same folder on my PC