# My shapefiles keep disappearing from my catalog

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, catalog-window

I'm fairly new to ArcMap 10.8.2. I am currently working on mapping out a landfill in ArcMap using a variety of shapefiles. When I first made the shapefiles, they stored properly in a folder I created on my desktop, but after I closed out (I saved) then reopened ArcMap, when I looked in my catalog for my shapefiles in the designated folder, they were gone.

Now, the shapefiles are still in the folder on my computer, but they don't show up in the catalog when I click on the folder. Also, when I click on the little plus sign to show the drop down of the folder, the plus sign disappears and only the folder remains.

Also, the folder appears empty in the catalog even though I am sure that the folder has the files in the folder on my computer. I tried to move them to a new folder and create a new folder connection which worked once, but when I closed out and reopened it, I had the same issue as before.

Comment: It seem that ArcMap doesn't recognize your shapefile as valid data source (and as a result show the folder as empty), could you confirm (by using windows explorer) that the shapefile are still fully in the folder ? (by fully in the folder I mean that all part of shapefile are present, you should have at minima 3 file for each shapefile .shp, .dbf and .shx).

Comment: You may also check that the full path to your shapefile doesn't contain space or special character

Comment: Hello J.R, I know that they're actually present because I can see the shapefiles in my viewport, so it's reading them fine, but I just can't see the shapefiles in my catalog

Comment: You could rename you normal. gxt file (with ArcGIS closed) and see if the new one created by ArcCatalog on restarting works.  If so your ArcCatalog template file was corrupted.  If there is no change and you have customizations you didn't want to lose, you can delete the new normal.gxt and rename your old one back to it. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/180662/creating-a-new-normal-template-in-arccatalog